# C++ boost::shared_ptr & boost::weak_ptr & dynamic_cast

Tags: boost, dynamic-cast, weak-ptr

I have something like this:

```
enum EFood{
    eMeat,
    eFruit
};

class Food{
};

class Meat: public Food{
    void someMeatFunction();
};

class Fruit: public Food{
    void someFruitFunction();
};

class FoodFactory{
    vector<Food*> allTheFood;
    Food* createFood(EFood foodType){
        Food* food=NULL;
        switch(foodType){
            case eMeat:
                food = new Meat();
                break;
            case eFruit:
                food = new Fruit();
                break;
        }
        if(food)
            allTheFood.push_back(food);
        return food;
    }
};

int foo(){
    Fruit* fruit = dynamic_cast<Fruit*>(myFoodFactory->createFood(eFruit));
    if(fruit)
        fruit->someFruitFunction();
}
```

now I want to change my application to use boost shared_ptr and weak_ptr such that i can delete my food instance in a single place. it would look like this:

```
class FoodFactory{
    vector<shared_ptr<Food> > allTheFood;
    weak_ptr<Food> createFood(EFood foodType){
        Food* food=NULL;
        switch(foodType){
            case eMeat:
                food = new Meat();
                break;
            case eFruit:
                food = new Fruit();
                break;
        }

        shared_ptr<Food> ptr(food);
        allTheFood.push_back(ptr);
        return weak_ptr<Food>(ptr);
    }
};

int foo(){
    weak_ptr<Fruit> fruit = dynamic_cast<weak_ptr<Fruit> >(myFoodFactory->createFood(eFruit));
    if(shared_ptr<Fruit> fruitPtr = fruit.lock())
        fruitPtr->someFruitFunction();
}
```

but the problem is that the dynamic_cast doesn't seem to work with weak_ptr

how do I get a `weak_ptr<Fruit>` out of a `weak_ptr<Food>` if i know that the object it points to is of derived type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Direct casting from `weak_ptr<A>` to `weak_ptr<B>` will surely don't work, I think you have to convert it to a `shared_ptr` and then use the casting functionality of shared_ptr:

```
weak_ptr<Food> food = myFoodFactory->createFood(eFruit)
weak_ptr<Fruit> fruit = weak_ptr<Fruit>(dynamic_pointer_cast<Fruit>(food.lock());
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `dynamic_cast` with `shared_ptr` because it would require to change the template of the object. What in fact you want to do is a `dynamic_cast` on the internal pointer. To do this you could do a `dynamic_cast` on the pointer returned by `get` but that would not be so clean because the reference would not be shared(irrelevant in your case since you're using `weak_ptr` but relevant when using `shared_ptr`) and creating a share_ptr on this would be undefined resulting on a double delete.

Use `dynamic_pointer_cast` to do this but the two types still need to be related. In other words `dynamic_cast<T*>(r.get())` needs to be well formed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS to improve performance if you're not bound to multithreading, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8966130/1067933

Comment: If this question is a duplicate of the one you link to, please flag the question as such, providing this link.